# What I missing here, using ImageFolder to get the full folder name as labels for MNIST-double dataset images?

Tags: python-3.x, label, pytorch-dataloader

I would like to use [dataset.ImageFolder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uesf3.png) to create an Image Dataset.

My current image directory structure looks like this:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uesf3.png): [In train images, I have subfolders which are my labels contain 00, 01, and so on. In each folder, images contain double digits corresponding to each label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uesf3.png)

**Here is the code I used followed by the output where the labels does not. match with the images**

*paths here*

```
data_dir = "/home/mhamdan/hamdan/MNIST_muldigits/data/double_mnist"
train_dir = data_dir + '/train' # training_set contains training dataset
val_dir = data_dir + '/val'  #contains validation dataset
test_dir = data_dir + '/test'  #contains test dataset
```

*Loading the data here*

```
#Load the dataset with Image Folder
trainset = datasets.ImageFolder(train_dir, transform = transformation)
valset = datasets.ImageFolder(val_dir, transform = transformation)
testset = datasets.ImageFolder(test_dir, transform = transformation)
```

*Data loaders*

```
#define data loaders
batch_size = 32
train_loader = DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True,num_workers=2)
val_loader = DataLoader(valset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True,num_workers=2)
test_loader = DataLoader(testset, batch_size=batch_size,num_workers=1)
```

*Here is the plotting of random training images*

```
examples = enumerate(train_loader)
batch_idx, (example_data, example_targets) = next(examples)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(6):
  plt.subplot(2,3,i+1)
  plt.tight_layout()
  plt.imshow(example_data[i][0], cmap='gray', interpolation='none')
  plt.title("Ground Truth: {}".format(example_targets[1]))
  plt.xticks([])
  plt.yticks([])
fig
```

*As you see here, the labels are different than images*
[labels differ than images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU5S3.png)

*Each subfolders contains a unique label associated with a label*
[image: subfolder iamge]

here the images in 01 subdirectory[image: 01]

Last update after using the index. [image: still the same issue, after update the index]

Comment: What does your subfolder like 00,01 contains ? Can you post the image of those too

Comment: Thanks @KnowledgeGainer for your prompt reply. 

Each subfolders contains a unique label associated with image of that class. Like below in the updated screenshot. 

Thanks,

Comment: The first 2 photos are same ? Can you please post the image of inside of 001 subdirectory, inside structure of 001 sub folder

Comment: Thanks @KnowledgeGainer, 
I can explain the root and subdirectories here:

Comment: Thanks @KnowledgeGainer, 
I can explain the root and subdirectories here:
1) train >>> contains subdirectories of combinations of digits as double eg. 00, 01, 02 and so on. 
2) In each subfolder, eg. 00 : contains of unique label names associated with the corresponding images. Please, See the last screen shot above.

Comment: While printing the labels, it should be   plt.title("Ground Truth: {}".format(example_targets[i])), instead of 1

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in printing the labels,

> Here is the plotting of random training images

For this, the code should be,

```
examples = enumerate(train_loader)
batch_idx, (example_data, example_targets) = next(examples)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(6):
  plt.subplot(2,3,i+1)
  plt.tight_layout()
  plt.imshow(example_data[i][0], cmap='gray', interpolation='none')
  plt.title("Ground Truth: {}".format(example_targets[i]))
  plt.xticks([])
  plt.yticks([])
fig
```

In your code, it was example_targets[**1**]), instead of **i**.

Comment: I tried that before, but I still got the images doe not match with the labels. For example in the screenshot above, the label is 20, whereas the image contains 28, ans the same of for others. Please see the last image. Many thanks

Comment: @MohammedHamdan Hmmm, that's really strange, you tried the above code and it's not giving the desired output, right ?

Comment: indeed, I posted the output plot in the last image. Really strange. Is there any suggestion to reformulate the structure of the dateset.  Thanks

Comment: @MohammedHamdan last image is showing sub folder 20

Comment: Yes, the structure in the datasets all are well. But when plotting the labels differ than image content. Like label 20 while the image contents 28.

Comment: @MohammedHamdan In your data loader, remove num_workers,     I am talking about this line: train_loader = DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True,num_workers=2)

Comment: @KnowledgGainer, removed num_workers, however still not works. same results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to my question by taking the indexes as dictionary `labelsdec = trainset.class_to_idx` and by extracting the keys as labels/classes using this functions

```
def getList(dict):
list = []
for key in dict.keys():
    list.append(key)
      
return list
def getList(dict):
list = []
for key in dict.keys():
    list.append(key)
      
return list
  
classes = getList(labelsdec)
```

Thin plotting 10 images:

```
def imshow(img):
    img = img / 2 + 0.5  # unnormalize
    plt.imshow(np.transpose(img, (1, 2, 0)))  # convert from Tensor image
# obtain one batch of training images
data_iter = iter(train_loader)
images, lbls = data_iter.next()
images = images.numpy() # convert images to numpy for display
# plot the images in the batch, along with the corresponding labels
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
# display 20 images
for idx in np.arange(10):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 10/2, idx+1, xticks=[], yticks=[])
    imshow(images[idx])
    label = lbls[idx]
    ax.set_title(classes[lbls[idx]])
```

Here is how it looks see image[image: desired output where labels of sub directories matches the image content]