# How to prepare and use the sub-directories Names as Labels for a CNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch

I have dataset contains of train, val and test sets. I want to use the subdirectories name as labels. For more info. please this [What I missing here, using ImageFolder to get the full folder name as labels for MNIST-double dataset images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67398465/what-i-missing-here-using-imagefolder-to-get-the-full-folder-name-as-labels-for/67414923?noredirect=1#comment119167250_67414923)

Comment: sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer

Comment: **See this answer** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67398465/what-i-missing-here-using-imagefolder-to-get-the-full-folder-name-as-labels-for?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: From now on be more descriptive about your question. I don't even know which framework you are talking about.